# apply function which return dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below code works but wish if get better way to implement.

The idea is combine first dataframe with another dataframe, which depends on first dataframe's row values.

```
import pandas as pd 

def getdf(x):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        {'rkey': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
         'rval': [x, x*2, x*3]})
    return df2

def combine(df):
    data = []
    dfout = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(len(df)):
        df1 = df.iloc[i, :].to_frame().transpose().reset_index()
        df2 = getdf(df1['lval'].values[0])
        df3 = df1.join(df2, how='outer',lsuffix='', rsuffix='')
        #print(df3)
        dfout = pd.concat([dfout,df3],axis=0,ignore_index=True)
    #dfout.reset_index()
    dfout = dfout[dfout.columns.drop('index')]
    return dfout

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'key': ['A','B','C'],
     'lval': [1,3,5]})

print(df1)
```

output:

```
  key  lval
0   A     1
1   B     3
2   C     5
   key lval rkey  rval
0    A    1    X     1
1  NaN  NaN    Y     2
2  NaN  NaN    Z     3
3    B    3    X     3
4  NaN  NaN    Y     6
5  NaN  NaN    Z     9
6    C    5    X     5
7  NaN  NaN    Y    10
8  NaN  NaN    Z    15
```

Comment: I am not sure if there is a question here or not.  If you are asking us to write the function, that's not our purpose. We don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: @lucky1928 offered his own option

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following option: here, using [np.multiply](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html), all values are calculated at once and rows are created in the rkey, rkey_df1 columns for which the merging occurs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

amount = len(df1['lval'])

rkey = np.tile(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], amount)
rkey_df1 = np.repeat(df1['key'], amount)
rval = np.multiply(df1['lval'].values[:, np.newaxis], np.array([1, 2, 3])).ravel()

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': rkey, 'rval': rval, 'rkey_df1': rkey_df1})

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  rkey  rval rkey_df1
0    X     1        A
1    Y     2        A
2    Z     3        A
3    X     3        B
4    Y     6        B
5    Z     9        B
6    X     5        C
7    Y    10        C
8    Z    15        C
```

Then you can do a right-hand merge:

```
print(pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['lval', 'key'], 
               right_on=['rval', 'rkey_df1'], how='right'))
```

Output:

```
   key  lval rkey  rval rkey_df1
0    A   1.0    X     1        A
1  NaN   NaN    Y     2        A
2  NaN   NaN    Z     3        A
3    B   3.0    X     3        B
4  NaN   NaN    Y     6        B
5  NaN   NaN    Z     9        B
6    C   5.0    X     5        C
7  NaN   NaN    Y    10        C
8  NaN   NaN    Z    15        C
```